# How can I call a function by touching a button in html5

Tags: javascript, html

I want to call a function on touching a button in html5. I'm making a game for mobile.

Answer (score 2):

Try binding the 'touchstart' event .

Here is some documentation for touch events: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Touch_events

```
element.addEventListener("touchstart", touchHandler);
function touchHandler(){ /* your code here*/}
```

Comment: Hi Gabitz, consider providing a link, example, or a little bit more depth or detail to your answer.  As it stands, this is more of a comment than an actual answer.

Comment: Your edit doesn't help matters.  Try actually adding examples to your answer.. not just pointing the user in a vague direction.

Comment: How about now? I don't think that the link i've pointed is a vaque direction. There is an usage example and good explanation.

Comment: @gabitzish - Removed my downvote, and +1 to you sir! Thank you for fixing your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

In HTML you could do it like this:

```
<button onclick="yourFunction()">Click here</button>
```

In JavaScript you could do it like this;

```
function yourFunction(e){
    doSomething();
}
document.getElementById("yourButtonId").onclick=yourFunction;
```

In Javascript remember: do AFTER the page has loaded, not before!

Comment: Click event has some issues on mobile devices. I had problems with the 'click area' on iOS, it was misplaced.

Comment: i need ontouch function not onclick